# flask-admin TypeError: Can't compile non template nodes

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am following a tutorial on youtube on getting flask-admin to work. Right now i am just trying to get it to work in routes.py to see it working (I've also tried models and it fails every time).

Here is my code

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
admin = Admin(app)
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
```

when i do http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/ in my browser i get an error

```
builtins.TypeError
TypeError: Can't compile non template nodes
```

I've spent the last 3 hours trying to figure out what is going on but it doesn't make any sense and i can't find any similar issues anywhere.

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",   line 1997, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
        return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
        return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 452, in index
        return self.render(self._template)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 308, in render
        return render_template(template, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
        return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
        return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
        return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
        template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 125, in load
        code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 581, in compile
        defer_init=defer_init)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 543, in _generate
        optimized=self.optimized)
      File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py", line 78, in generate
        raise TypeError('Can\'t compile non template nodes')
    TypeError: Can't compile non template nodes
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your code. What version of flask admin are you running? Have you tried to upgrade all flask components using `pip`?

Comment: So I'm on pip 9.0.1 right now. im wondering if that's installing a deprecated version of flask-admin. The reason for 9.0.1 is we are also using Flask-Ask and that only works with 9.0.1

Comment: Yeah, maybe give upgrading pip a try. But what I original asked was the version of `flask_admin`. You can get it by running `print(flask_admin.__version__)`.

Comment: I am not sure why but when i do that i get "NameError: name 'flask_admin' is not defined" I double checked, flask-admin is currently installed.

Comment: Well you have to import it first.

Comment: Got it thanks so much for your help. Version 1.5.3